# Realm Swift, relationship and memory space error

Tags: json, swift, memory-management, realm

In my code, I have two class linked like this :

```
class parent: Object {
    dynamic var id:Int = 0
    let children = List<child>()
    ...
}

class child: Object {
    dynamic var myParent = parent?
    ...
}
```

I have done that to be able to find easily the parent of a child and his children of a parent. 
But now, when I want to get a Parent :

```
let myParent = realm.objects(parent).filter("id == 1").first
```

I get a very big JSON string in return. Because my parent have many children, and for each children I display the parent AND the children...So my json is nearly infinite.

Can this be the problem of my error "Cannot allocate memory size" ?
Would it be better to declare my child like this :

```
class child: Object {
    dynamic var myParentId:Int = 0
    ...
}
```

I don't know if a very big json can be a reason for a memory space error.

I hope my questions is clear enough :)

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What do you mean by JSON? How is JSON being combined with Realm here?

Comment: Actually, when I do a PRINT of a json result, it displays a JSON. It is this JSON I'm talking about. Is it better? :)

Comment: Ahh okay! Haha yeah, that's not really JSON per-se, more just how Xcode is printing out the objects in the console. They look pretty similar though!

Comment: Oh ok ^^, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can indeed manually manage the 2 relationships between a child and a parent, as you've discovered, it can be quite tricky.

Realm provides a support for [inverse relationships](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#inverse-relationships) where an object can look up which objects it belongs to.

```
class parent: Object {
    dynamic var id:Int = 0
    let children = List<child>()
    ...
}

class child: Object {
    let parent = LinkingObjects(fromType: parent.self, property: "children").first
    ...
}
```

That should hopefully automate what you're trying to do here. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's exactly what I was looking for. I will try this and hope it'll fix my memory issue.